# AndroidManifest.xml space in label (Error compiling)

Tags: compilation, label

I have error when I compile the android project.
Curiously, there is a space in android:label.

Error is in the file AndroidManifest.xml of the build directory.

```
    <activity
       android:name="com.example.blepeigneul.papaoutejellybean.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@st ring/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Why a space android:label ???

> @st ring

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved.

I had an error in AndrodManifest.xml source file (not in build project).